# R: What is the error with here "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : numeric 'envir' arg not of length one"

Tags: r, linear-regression, trendline

I'm trying to estimate the trend function to a set of data.

I'm getting the following error.

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

iPod dataset was originally 
Month      iPod
2004-01     17
.            .
.            .
.            .

```
library(readr)
iPod <- read.csv("~/Downloads/iPod.csv")
time <- seq(2004,2019+8/12,by=1/12)
iPod = iPod[,2]
plot(time,iPod,type='l')
time2 <- time^2
quad.mod <- lm(formula=iPod~time + time2, data=iPod)
lines(time,quad.mod$fitted.values,col='red')
```

I do get the plot but I'm not sure what the error is/isn't doing.

(This is my first time posting on stack overflow so I'm sorry if I'm making some formatting error)

Comment: If you use `lm` with the `data = iPod` argument, columns used in the formula `iPod~time + time2` need to be present in your `iPod` `data.frame`. In other words, `iPod` needs to be a `data.frame` with columns `iPod`, `time` and `time2`. Compare this with `lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)` and take a look at the structure of `mtcars`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers what would happen if i don't include the data.frame? Like in    lm(iPod~time+time2).

Comment: Without `data` argument R looks for the referenced objects in the current environment (which is usually the global environment). It's generally better/cleaner to use `lm` with the `data` argument.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I see, thank you for the help!

Comment: @MauritsEvers you are very kind and helpful to new site users.